# Proving that $\int^2_0fdx\ge1$ for a convex function

Tags: calculus

Suppose an $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, non-negtative and convex. It is also given that $f(1)=1$.

Prove that $\int^2_0fdx\ge1$.

This is a question from my Calculus II homework.
I know that I should use these properties of convex functions:

$\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R} \forall \lambda \in[0,1]: f(\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b)\le \lambda f(a)+(1-\lambda)f(b)$

$\forall x\forall x_0:f(x)\ge f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$

but I can't figure out how they would help me calculate the integral of $f$.

Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: *Hint.* What happens if you integrate both sides of $f(x) \geq f(1)+f'(1)(x-1)$ from $0$ to $2$?

Comment: The second property only is true when f is differentiable. This is probably above your pay grade but convexity implies the derivative exists a.e so you can still use this property.

Comment: Jensen’s inequality also works I think

Comment: @SangchulLee Note that it isn't given that $f$ is differentiable at $1$.

Comment: @GBA That's a fair point but i think it still works. We know it must be differentiable at points arbitrarily close to $1$ so pick $1+\delta$ s.t $f(1+\delta)=1-\epsilon$ and you get that the integral is larger than $1-o(\epsilon)$ for all epsilon. But I think this is too complciated...

Comment: Well then can I just assume in my solution that $f$ is differentiable at 1, or will that not be accepted?

Comment: @GBA, The lower bound can be replaced by any supporting line for general convex $f$ (or we may simply replace $f'(1)$ by either of the one-sided derivatives $f_{\pm}'(1)$). I just thought that OP is implicitly assuming $f$ is differentiable (since it is a calculus question).

Comment: Hint: the fact that $f$ is nonnegative is irrelevant. Show that $\int_0^2 f(x) dx = \int_0^1 (f(1 + x) + f(1 - x)) dx$; apply convexity. In fact, the integral will be at least 2.

Comment: @MarkSaving Now that is the slick solution here :) No need for any complicated assumption or knowledge of Jensens. Post it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let’s note that we can actually drop the assumption that $f$ is nonnegative and strengthen the conclusion to $\int_0^2 f(x) dx \geq 2$. Technically, we can even drop the assumption that $f$ is continuous, since that actually follows from convexity.

Step 1: Show $\int_0^2 f(x) dx = \int_0^1 (f(1 + x) + f(1 - x)) dx$.

Step 2: apply convexity to conclude $f(1 + x) + f(1 - x) \geq 2$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

Step 3: conclude $\int_0^1 (f(1 + x) + f(1 - x)) dx \geq 2$.

Comment: I suppose that does the job, but could you guide me through the first step?

Comment: @YuvalMoreno Step 1 involves the basic properties of integrals. Split up the $\int_0^2$ into $\int_0^1 + \int_1^2$, reparametrise the two integrals, and combine them into one integral.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\int^2_0fdx < 1$, then $f$ must have a point below $x+2y = 2$ (otherwise the integral would be greater than 1).

Comment: That line has area $0$ under integration from $0$ to $2$

Comment: It is 2, not 1. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If for all $x < 1$ one has $f(x) \geq 1$ then the desired conclusion is immediate since the integral from $0$ to $1$ is already at least $1$.

Suppose there is some $x < 1$ for which $f(x) < 1$. Then if $y > 1$, by convexity the point $(1,f(1)) = (1,1)$ lies on or below the segment connecting $(x, f(x))$ to $(y, f(y))$. Since $f(x) < 1$, this implies $f(y) > 1$. This will hold for all $y > 1$ so this time the integral from $1$ to $2$ will be greater than $1$.